# How to update cells referencing other sheet when sheet name is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet for registering hours worked in a project. Each student has their own sheet in the document for registering hours, and there is a summary page where the hours of each activity and each student. This spreadsheet is a blueprint for the students, so I have filled in Student1, Student2, etc. in some cells, and when the students change these cells the name of the corresponding sheet should change as well.

To change the name of the spreadsheets I have used this (simplified) code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C7') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(e.oldValue).setName(e.value)
  }
}
```

This changes the name of the correct sheet. The problem is that in cell C8 I have
`=INDIRECT(CONCAT(C$7;"!C112"))`, which worked when I wrote it, but when I change the value in cell C7 I get an error saying:

```
Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'ChangedName!C112'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

even if the appropriate sheet changed name to "ChangedName"
If I reenter the formula in the cell it again displays the correct value from the sheet "ChangedName"

I would like to update these cells after the sheet name changes, so I never get these errors.
I have made it work in excel, but when I tried using excel on onedrive to collaborate my other forumlas broke

Edit: Solved it. If I used:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mainsheet).getRange("C8:G16").setValues(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mainsheet).getRange("C8:G16").getFormulas())
```

it took a couple of seconds, but everything updated as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. If I used:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mainsheet).getRange("C8:G16").setValues(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mainsheet).getRange("C8:G16").getFormulas())
```

it took a couple of seconds, but everything updated as it should.